# Cannot see image in designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, mvvm

I have a view which displays some image using a Binding. It works fine at runtime, but I can't see the image in design mode (I use a fake ViewModel as DataContext).

```
public class DesignTimeData
{
    public string ImageSource { get { return "/WpfApplication1;component/banner.png"; } }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DesignTimeData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

What is strange is that this doesn't work:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
```

But this does:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
```

Am I missing something? 
Is this a bug is VS2010's designer? 
Is there something I can do to fix this (besides using the ugly `ControlTemplate` trick)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer seems to have a problem with a partial WPF Pack URI.

Either use a full [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get { return "pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/banner.png"; }
}
```

Or just the image file name:

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get { return "banner.png"; }
}
```